# XAMPP, WAMP, SIMILAR: Slow speed with xdebug

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, apache, xampp

I use XAMPP on windows 7, with Visual Studio and XDebug.
But in 2 years not solved the big problem, and now im very frustrated.
Localhost Wordpress websites in my localhost xampp server are very too slow.

Load a page take 3-4 seconds with XDebug enabled, 1-2 seconds if disabled.
This is incredible for many reasons like:

1) My PC is super fast: 2xSSD, 16GB RAM, 8CORE CPU, but XAMPP not use my power and stay slow.

2) When website is live on a shared hosting of 80$/years, it is more fast.

With this situation performance seem not related to PC power, so I think if i have for example 128GB RAM, 10xSSD in RAID and more, performance stay same. But how can be this possible?

I already tried all solutions found on web:

1) Enabled PHP accellerator (not change nothing)

2) Enable / disable lots of php.ini options

3) Encrease php memory limit

4) Change host file of windows.

Nothing improve performance. I not think i will found a solution, but if there is someone that can explain me why hardware can not improve performance is almost a useful info :)

Thank you!

Comment: Off the top of my head - your computer is designed to be a "do anything, and do it well" machine, while a web server is designed to be a "do only web things, but do them incredibly well" machine.  So it may not be strictly a matter of how fast/good your computer is, but instead the problem may just be that it's not a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution, disable xdebug and enable it only when required:

1. Open php.int from XAMPP > Apache > config > php.int
2. Move these line to top: zend_extension =
   "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.5-vc11.dll"  (or your path)
3. Disable it most of time with char ; and when I need the debug I
   uncomment it and restart apache